# PyTorch code stops with message "Killed". What killed it?

Tags: linux, pytorch

I train a network on GPU with Pytorch. However, after at most 3 epochs, code stops with a message :

`Killed`

No other error message is given.
I monitored the memory and gpu usage, there were still space during the run. I reviewed the /var/sys/dmesg to find a detailed message regarding to this, however no message with "kill" was entered. What might be the problem?

Cuda version: 9.0
Pytorch version: 1.1.0

Comment: Unfortunately no. Spesifically, dmesg -T| grep -E -i -B100 'killed process' returns empty and I don't think there is a resource starvation.

Comment: I don't have permission the access it

Comment: I do not have sudo access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to give an idea to people who will enconter this:

Apparently, Slurm was installed on the machine so that I needed to give the tasks on Slurm.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you did?

Answer (score 11):

If you had root access, you could check whether this is memory issue or not by `dmesg` command.

In my case, the process was killed by kernel due to `out of memory`.
I found the cause to be saving tensors require grad to a list and each of those stores an entire computation graph, which consumes significant memory.

I fixed the issue by saving `.detach()` tensor instead of saving tensors returned by loss function to the list.

Answer (score 9):

You can type "dmesg" on your terminal and scroll down to the bottom. It will show you the message of why it is killed.

Since you mentioned PyTorch, the chances are that your process is killed due to "Out of Memory". To resolve this, reduce your batch size till you no longer see the error.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Man, my batch size is 4 , I am trying the code on a dataset with 10 samples.